# How to break out of infinite while loop?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

Here is the code giving me trouble:

```
    String more = "yes";
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (more != "no") {
            //do stuff          
            System.out.println("Want to add more? (yes or no)");
            more = in.nextLine();
    }
```

So long as the user does not enter "no," the loop should continue. The issue is that when I enter no, it still doesn't stop.

Comment: use while(!more.equals("no"))

Comment: You can't compare 2 strings with `==` this is only used for comparing values of simple types `int, char, double...` or references of objects. Now, in your case you'll need to use : `while (!more.equals ("no"))`

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you!